# Default Radio value not get cleared or deselect after choose new value

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group, android-radiogroup

in for loop I have setChecked, but after choosing new value does not get deselected. Both the values get selected which is previous setChecked value and newly selected value.

```
textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(context);

textInputLayout.setPadding(0, -65, 0, -20);
for (int i = 0; i < formElement.getRadioOptions().size(); i++) {
    RadioButton radiobutton1 = new RadioButton(context);
    radiobutton1.setText(formElement.getRadioOptions().get(i).getValue());
    radiobutton1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.meetingNoteCL));

    radiobutton1.setChecked(formElement.getValue().equals(formElement.getRadioOptions().get(i).getValue()));

    rg.addView(radiobutton1);
}
textInputLayout.setTypeface(FontUtils.getFontTypeRegular(context));

rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
        int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
        int idx = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);

        formElement.setKey(formElement.getRadioOptions().get(idx).getKey());
        formElement.setValue(formElement.getRadioOptions().get(idx).getValue());

    }
});


viewMap.put(formElement.getTagOrToString(), rg);
addViewToView(textInputLayout, rg);
```

Comment: Experts  kindly help on this

Comment: Please provide a minimum **complete** example and add some details about what specific behavior you see that is different from what you expect.